# Insert multiple rows to Html table at once

Tags: asp.net-core, html-table, master-detail

I am working on a Master Detail CRUD operations in an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I am trying to perform the Create operation of both Master and Detail models at once, i want to save an order and its order lines (the number of the order lines is the value of the input quantite):

```
public class Order
{        
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
   
    [Required]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; } = new List<OrderLine>();       
}
public class OrderLine
{           
    [Key]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Designation{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Serial{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }        
}
```

OrderController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        Order order= new Order();
        order.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine() { OrderLineId = 1 });
        return PartialView("_AddOrderPartialView", order);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Order order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            _dbcontext.Order.Add(order);
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

_AddOrderPartialView.cshtml:

```
    @model Order

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_AddOrderPartialView";

}


<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="addOrder" aria-labelledby="addOrderLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Order</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                     .......

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
                        <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" id="quantite" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    .......

                    <h3>Order Lines</h3>
                    
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="orderLinesTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>   
                                <th>Designation</th>
                                <th>Serial</th>
                                <th>State</th>                                    
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>       
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderLines.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OrderLines[i].Designation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OrderLines[i].Serial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OrderLines[i].State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>    
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    
    $("#quantite").on('change', function () {
            
        var RowNumber = document.getElementById('quantite').value;
        var table = document.getElementById('orderLinesTable');
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;
        $("#orderLinesTable tbody").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < RowNumber-1; i++) {    
            var newRow = table.insertRow();
            newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;
            
        }    

    });
</script>
```

The problem is that this code saves only the first order line in the database. any help?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your POST method, is there more then, or ecactly 1 OrderLine in your order?

Comment: There is just ONE OrderLine.

Comment: Are you getting the full list while submitting the request to server? Have to checked what exactly posting on submittion from `javascript`?

Comment: It posts only the first order line.